# How to sort createdAt field from firestore v9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to firebase. I want to retrieve all the data via userId then sort the createdAt field to desc order but it doesnt work for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
 const q = query(collectionRef, where('userId', '==',user.uid),orderBy('createdAt','desc'));

 onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  const documents = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    return {
      ...doc.data(),
      doc_id: doc.id
     };
   });
   setIsLoading(false);
   setTodos(documents);
 });
}, []);
```

Comment: Have you created the [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes)?

Comment: PS: In this case, you should add an [error callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors) to see the potential error message.

Comment: You nailed the two most likely causes Renaud.  --- While they are only troubleshooting steps, this type of problem is so common that I'd recommend writing it up (with some additonial detail) as an answer.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, just followed your suggestion 

Answer (score 1):

Your problem most probably comes from the fact that Firestore misses the [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes) corresponding to your query.

Since you didn't add an error callback in your `onSnapshot()` method call, you cannot see the error. Adding a callback will firstly allow you to confirm that it is a problem of missing composite index and, secondly, show you an URL ([in the error message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message)) that will allow you to automatically build this index.

Comment: Oh okay i see. I'll give it a try 

Comment: Mad! It works. Definitely was the index issue. Added the index on firestore now its perfect. Thank you